# Why do we need constructor in this code?

Tags: constructor

I heard that constructor is usually used for initializing variables but It just has 'console.log' here. Is constructor essential for every contract?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract WavePortal {
   uint256 totalWaves;

   event NewWave(address indexed from, uint256 timestamp, string message);

   struct Wave {
       address waver;
       string message;
       uint256 timestamp;
   }

   Wave[] waves;

   constructor() payable {
       console.log("We have been constructed!");
   }

   function wave(string memory _message) public {
       totalWaves += 1;
       console.log("%s waved w/ message %s", msg.sender, _message);

       waves.push(Wave(msg.sender, _message, block.timestamp));

       emit NewWave(msg.sender, block.timestamp, _message);
    
       uint256 prizeAmount = 0.0001 ether;
       require(
           prizeAmount <= address(this).balance,
           "Trying to withdraw more money than the contract has."
       );
       (bool success, ) = (msg.sender).call{value: prizeAmount}("");
       require(success, "Failed to withdraw money from contract.");
   }

   function getAllWaves() public view returns (Wave[] memory) {
       return waves;
   }

   function getTotalWaves() public view returns (uint256) {
       console.log("We have %d total waves!", totalWaves);
       return totalWaves;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console.log is only there for debuging purpose.

constructor function is optional, you can omit, which is equivalent to `constructor() {}`.

In your code, the constructor is marked as `payable` though, so one can send ether while deploying this contract, which is not possible if use the default constructor.